Encoding image with an generator matrix G with zero padding
I want to encoding given image with generator matrix G which is already given(ex. (7,4) Hamming code).
I heard that we should do mod-2 vector-matrix multiply with generator G for data bits X to make codeword C.
For example, data bits size is 1 * 4, then C will be 1 * 7 code because G is 4 * 7.
However, image size is not vector, but array. How can we do encoding with G? I heard that we should also do proper zero-padding.
I didn't know the principle of this encoding, so is there anyone can help me for understanding this principle?
Thank you so much!
